# Microarray hierarchical clustering and PCA with python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pca, biopython, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to analyze microarray data using hierarchical clustering of the microarray columns (results from the individual microarray replicates) and PCA.

I'm new to python. I have python 2.7.3, biopyhton, numpy, matplotlib, and networkx.

Are there functions in python or biopython (similar to MATLAB's clustergram and mapcaplot) that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is great for neuroscience, congrats for your choice. Sometimes the ressources are harder to find than for Matlab, but they're free, you will find an active community and lot of support.

A good starting point will be the [Neuroimaging in Python](http://nipy.sourceforge.net/) project and its subprojects, e.g., nitime. I recommend subscribing to and asking at the mailing list, those guys are really clever and like to help.

For PCA, you could also try [Modular Toolkit for Dataprocessing in Python](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/), a nice library of data processing algorithms.

For clustering in general, I recommend [Scipy Clustering](http://code.google.com/p/scipy-cluster/).

HTH,
Thorsten

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use R Bioconductor and free software like Expander and MeV. Good flexible choice is a Cluster software with TreeViews. You can also run R and STATA or JMP from your Python codes and completely automate your data management.

Answer (score 0):

R has a great assortment of tools to do exactly what you're describing vis-a-vis microarray analysis with hierarchical clustering. Here's a link to a course I took that details how to do microarray analysis with R. Hope [this](https://functionalgenomics.wordpress.com/) helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've used [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) for clustering and other machine learning applications in python. I've found that the scikit approach is generally intuitive and, happily, things work right out of the box.

There are a number of [clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) algorithms available, including [agglomerative clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering) which is one hierarchical clustering approach.

In addition to clustering there are a host of machine learning algorithms both supervised and unsupervised. There are also a variety of tools supporting [feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction), [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cross_validation), etc. Preprocessing tools include [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), and a lot more.

Definitely worth checking out.